# jQuery AJAX call returning an empty response

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a web page with a small form in it.

[image]

HTML code for the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body_services">

<?php

include_once 'DatabaseHandler.php';
$db = DatabaseHandler::getInstance();

//loading taxi service names for updating combobox
$queryLoadSids = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM taxi_services ORDER BY SID");
$queryLoadSids->execute();
$dropdown = "<select name='serviceID'>";
while ($row = $queryLoadSids->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['SID']}'>{$row['Name']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

?>

<div id="tasks">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="add" href="#">Add a new taxi service</a></li>
        <li><a id="update" href="#">Update a taxi service</a></li>
        <li><a id="delete" href="#">Delete a taxi service</a></li>
        <li><a id="view" href="#">View taxi services</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form id="cmbServiceIDs" name="sids">
<table width="380" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="serviceId">Select the Service ID</label></td>
    <td><?php echo $dropdown; ?></td>
    <td><input id="load" type="submit" value="Load" name="btnload" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<form id="frmUpdateService" name="Update" action="" method="post">
<table width="300" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="sid">Service ID</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" value="" style="text-align:right" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="cost">Cost</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cost" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="active">Active</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="active" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" /> <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When the Load button is clicked, it should run a query against a DB, return the results to populate the textboxes in the form. I'm using jQuery AJAX for this task.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#frmUpdateService").hide();
    $("#cmbServiceIDs").hide();

    $("#update").click(function()
    {
        $("#cmbServiceIDs").slideDown("slow");
        $("#frmUpdateService").hide();
    });

    $("#cmbServiceIDs").submit(function(e)
    {
        $("#frmUpdateService").fadeIn("slow");
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type        : 'GET',
            url         : 'request.php',
            data        : {'serviceID' : $("#serviceID").val()},
            dataType    : 'json',
            success     : function(response)
            {
                var loadedSID = response[0];
                var loadedName = response[1];
                var loadedCost = response[2];
                var loadedActive = response[3];

                $("#sid").append(loadedSID);
                $("#name").append(loadedName);
                $("#cost").append(loadedCost);
                $("#active").append(loadedActive);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the *request.php* page.

```
<?php

include_once 'DatabaseHandler.php';
$db = DatabaseHandler::getInstance();

$param = $_GET['serviceID'];

$queryLoadToUpdate = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM taxi_services WHERE SID = :serviceID");
$queryLoadToUpdate->bindParam(':serviceID', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryLoadToUpdate->execute();
$results = $queryLoadToUpdate->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

But when I run the page and click on the Load button, nothing appears in the textboxes. I looked into the response using Firebug and it shows an empty response. I checked the SQL query as well. No errors there either.

I have no idea what I should check or do next. Can anyone give any suggestions as to why its not working properly here?

Thank you.

Comment: And Google Chrome console what says ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes same thing as Firebug. Empty response.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: 75% is acceptable rate. Means 3/4 is accepted.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I always accept answers if they solve my problem.

Comment: Have you checked if the variable $results actually contains anything?

Comment: what's the status of the header?

Comment: @d1001001 good idea. I used a `if else` block and apparently it returned no results! I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: @itachi, nK0de - 33 out of 44 questions that were asked 2-12 months ago seems like an inactivity to me

Comment: @nK0de You can use var_dump() function and than you could see contents of $results in the response(even if it's empty, then you would see NULL).

Comment: @itachi `var_dump($results)` returns `bool(false)`. I don't know what to make of that

Comment: @nK0de - you can start a bounty, self-answer or event delete outdated questions to help clean StackOverflow up

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I shall do that.

Comment: @itachi I think I know why the query isn't returning any result. I just dumped the variable `$param` and it returned `NULL`.

Comment: @nK0de in this case, `bool(false)` means query failed. Why failed? I think you already found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the query was *not* working correctly because the value I supplied for the variable `$param` was `NULL`. I could figure that out using `var_dump`. Further checking led me to notice that the dropdown's selected value was not getting passed correctly because I hadn't specified an `id` on this line.

```
$dropdown = "<select name='serviceID'>";
```

I corrected it like this.

```
$dropdown = "<select id='serviceID' name='serviceID'>";
```

And in the jQuery code, changed this line

`data : {'serviceID' : $("#serviceID option:selected").val()},`

to this to get the value of the selected dropdown item.

```
data : {'serviceID' : $("#serviceID option:selected").val()},
```